# Как вернуть рандомное число в диапазоне [0, 1), то есть, от 0 (включительно) до 1 (но не включая 1)?

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Как вернуть рандомное число в  диапазоне [0, 1), то есть, от 0 (включительно) до 1 (но не включая 1)?

Так включает единицу:
`UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Random.NextDouble`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextdouble?view=netcore-3.1) – то, что вам нужно.

> Returns a random floating-point number that is greater than or equal to 0.0, and less than 1.0.